# QGIS line symbology problem

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a problem with line symbology, as you can see on the picture:
[image]

In the "sytle creator" window, you can see that my semi-ring are turned inside my polygon. But on the map, they are outside.

Is there a problem? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Rotation is set at 180°

Comment: Change the symbol rotation to 0°.

Comment: It has nothing to do with rotation or not. If I set rotation to 0°, now it is correct on my map, but not in my legend! So if I need a layout, my legend will not match with the map?!?

Comment: For me, it seems more that polygons (boundry) make a mistake with the in and out!

Comment: I just make a test on a anthor computer, and it's OK!!! Did you have an idea what I have done on my computer, that the symbol is flipping???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The symbols angle follows the line direction. If the polygons were digitized in a clockwise direction, the 1/2 circle symbols would be inside. If digitized counter-clockwise, they are outside.

[image]

To fix this, you must fix the digitization direction. You can either do this on the polygons themselves, or just when styling them.

Before rendering the polygon boundaries, use a geometry generator to properly set the line directions, using the expression `force_rhr($geometry)`

[image]

Comment: PERFECT... it is exactly this! Thank you very much!!!